# Accessing properties with special characters using Specflow.Assist .Dynamic

Tags: c#, dynamic, bdd, specflow

I have a Specflow table that has column headers with special characters like "CC $ Portion  Total" & "Dollar Value (total in C2C)".

```
var content = table.CreateDynamicSet();
```

when I create the dynamic set as above, It removes the spaces of above column headers. But I am unable to access them the properties as

```
content.CC$PortionTotal
```

or

```
content.DollarValue(totalinC2C)
```

because, C# gives errors when it see special charters like  $ , ( and )

Does anyone know how to  work around this ?

Tx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATED**
This is fixed in 1.1.0 of SpecFlow.Assist.Dynamic, which allows any character in the column headers. In the property this will be stripped out. Read about the [functionality here](https://github.com/marcusoftnet/SpecFlow.Assist.Dynamic/wiki/Conventions-used)

Oooouch ... yeah that will be a problem since those are reserved characters in C#. Right now the code will not handle this gracefully, so you're only resort is to rename the columns (write out "dollars" and lose the parenthesis for example).

Please raise an issue at GitHub and I'll see what I can do, but I fear that I'll have to just strip reserved chars out, leaving the names less understandable. But it will not crash on you, at least :)

Sorry about that. Hope my work around gave you some ideas to play with

Answer (score 0):

tx a lot for your swift reply, yes if we can strip out special characters like we do for spaces, that would be great.  Its oki to strip them out at step definition level I think (stake holders are not looking at that, but the feature file)  as all we want is to get hold of the property value to assert against actual results.

Even I asked my team if its possible to remove special characters from the feature file in our SBE session , but they thought its not a good idea as it reduces the redability of living documentation used by stakeholders. I am planning to iterate through the table headers and strip  out the  special characters and then create a dynamic set. Will raise a ticket, by the way, thanks for your contribution with this dynamic library. Its great!

Comment: I created an issue with my current idea here. https://github.com/marcusoftnet/SpecFlow.Assist.Dynamic/issues/11 What do you think?

Comment: I have fixed this now. It's in release 1.1.0 of SpecFlow.Assist.Dynamic. https://www.nuget.org/packages/SpecFlow.Assist.Dynamic/1.1.0. You can read about the functionality here: https://github.com/marcusoftnet/SpecFlow.Assist.Dynamic/issues/11

Answer (score 0):

Until Marcus fix this, we can work this around as below

```
            foreach (var header in table.Header)
        {
            table.RenameColumn(header, Regex.Replace(header, "[^0-9a-zA-Z]+", String.Empty));
        }
```